# AngularJS, Cloud Endpoints, Gapi client

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-js-client

I am building a web app using AngularJS. I wrote the backend using Google cloud endpoints and Google Datastore. The Gapi client in AngulrJS seems to take a 2/3 seconds to load on average. I deployed the app end to end in Google AppEngine but the Gapi client load time has not become any faster. Have you experienced this sort of problem before? Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you share some of the code you think is taking a long time?

Comment: if you don't require authentication through gapi client i suggest you avoid gapi client all together. We had quite a few troubles with gapi client this year. Using angulars $resource is what i'd do now.

Comment: Is it loading ``https://apis.google.com/js/client.js`` that takes a long time or is it the call to ``gapi.client.load`` that takes a long time?

Comment: gapi.client.load. So I am caching the client got back from the first call in Service now. So things are better. Wish I could download a generated client for web. It seems to have that option for iOS and Android.